# Router network seperation when an (unknown) device is connected via LAN?

Tags: network, router, internet, lan

I share a router (Asus RT-AX58U) with my flat mate. Because the rooms are on different floors it is of no use for him to use the wireless network (he doens't have the password).
He bought his own router, which is now connected via LAN to the main router (Asus RT-AX58U).
Is this a safe setup or should I somehow seperate his LAN network? If so, how do I do this?
I want to isolate our networks, such that he cannot see my internet activity or my devices (want to avoid router cascading or VPN

Comment: *"So in addition to my main question: Any tips of starting on home network security? So far youtube has been my best friend, but I don't mind doing a paid course somewhere."* -  I've removed this part since it is unrelated (and likely off-topic too). Please focus your question on on topic only.

Comment: While your specific router model supports a WLAN guest network it does not seem to offer the same isolation for LAN. This means it will not provide the isolation you want by its own.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you have any recommendations for ethernet LAN isolation? I've read there are a couple of ways to erradicate this problem.